# What is the purpose of the pairs of cylinders on the interstage of PSLV?

Tags: rockets, identify-this-object, launch-vehicle, isro, pslv

In the following images, it can be seen that the interstage (separating the first stage PS1 and the second stage PS2) of the Indian Space Research Organisation's (ISRO) [Polar Satellite Launch Vehicle (PSLV)](https://www.isro.gov.in/launchers/pslv) contains pairs of cylinders as indicated by the yellow and red rectangles respectively:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Original Image Source: [PSLV-C47 Gallery](https://www.isro.gov.in/pslv-c47-cartosat-3-mission/pslv-c47-gallery)</sup>

What is the purpose of these cylinders? Are they separation motors? Or, are they present for passive stability? Why are they flat at the top, will they not increase drag during the atmospheric regime?

If possible, kindly support your answer with references.

*Thank you in advance*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highly annotated photo says they are separation motors aka "retrorockets".

[image]

Also

[image]

> Ullage & Retro Rockets, attached to the outer surface of the PSLV, are
>   another interesting mechanism utilised in the Jettison process. The
>   PSLV uses 12 Retro Rockets - 8 for Stage I & 4 for Stage II; while 4
>   Ullage Rockets mounted on the body of Stage II activate during Stage I
>   separation. This photograph of the PSLV-C32, above, shows a clear view
>   of the Ullage & Retro rockets mounted on the body. Retro Rockets,
>   attached to the jettisoning body, imparts the jettison a velocity,
>   away from the PSLV, decelerating it, increasing the distance between
>   the two.

As far as being flat on the top, this last picture shows that they are at least angled.

Found [here](https://www.spansen.com/2017/02/pslv-stage-separation-case-for-launch.html)

Comment: +1: Thanks a lot! Now, I could be familiar while watching its launch on 27th :)

Comment: @Intellex that linked website seems pretty informative about PSLV - thanks for the question that led me to find it.

Comment: Yes, it's more informative than the official website!